# How to enable SSL Debug in Jetty?

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, osgi, pax-web

I am trying to resolve an SSLHandshakeException and for that, I am trying to enable SSL to debug mode, I have tried setting -Djavax.net.debug=ssl but it doesn't work, the logger only gives me information about classes like org.eclipse.util.ssl.SSLContextfactory and org.eclipse.util.ssl.X509, does this mean that Jetty doesn't use JSSE implementation in its core?

I am trying to visualize the logs in this format: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Jetty is embedded in a bundle (Karaf OSGi Framework) using Pax Web 7.x

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you starting Jetty? (standalone? jetty-home? embedded? from an IDE?)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt it is being started in an OSGi environment, it is embedded in PS4J Pax Web (https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/spaces/paxweb/overview), currently I am using Pax Web 7.x, thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can you post the entire Exception? It would help to see the details of how it's generated in your environment to see how to tweak your environment to produce logs.

Answer (score 0):

The following vm argument should do the trick:

`-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake`

or

`-Djavax.net.debug=ALL`

Comment: I thought passing the additional values could maybe provide more debug logging if present, thats the reason why I provided `keymanager,trustmanager,ssl:handshake` as additional values

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,keymanager,trustmanager,ssl,handshake` ?